# How do Android data files map to what I access with adb shell?

Tags: android, adb, oculusgo

I've made an app for Oculus Go (an Android device) that reads files from user storage.  I normally transfer such files from my Mac using Android File  Transfer, which shows a hierarchy like this:
[image: image of Android File Transfer].  But one user, also using a Mac, keeps having trouble where some files are not readable by my app.

We've verified that the data of the files is OK by pulling them back down (also with Android File Transfer) and comparing the md5 hash; they are identical.  So I'm thinking it might be a permissions issue.

But Android File Transfer doesn't show permissions, so I'm trying to examine them using adb, and this brings me to my question.  When I use:

```
adb shell ls -la sdcard/Android/data/com.luminaryapps.beatron/files
```

the result shows only the Unity folder (plus . and ..), no other folders at all.  And if I bravely append the name of one of the folders Android File Transfer shows (e.g. Achievement.song), I get the "No such file or directory" error.

So clearly these files are stored on my device someplace else, and Android File Transfer must be combining data from two different partitions or something into one location.  I've searched for and references like [2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage) and [3](http://www.stevesandroidguide.com/android-files/), but am none the wiser.  Can anyone explain what's going on?